# Error installing django-heroku Error: pg_config executable not found

Tags: django, heroku

I tried installing django-heroku via pip so I can deploy my project on heroku but during installation of django-heroku it tried to install psycopg2 along only to produce an error:
Error:pg_config executable not found.

pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.please add the directory containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the option:
python setup.py build_ext--pg-config/path/to/pg_config build...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

And I also wish to know if I'm required to pip install it since heroku installs the libaries specified in the requirements.txt file,if not required are there changes I need to make to my project before deployment.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not optimal solution but it did work for me.

```
pip install --no-dependencies django-heroku
```

Be sure to have other required packages installed.

```
pip install django
pip install whitenoise
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

P.S. I have already had postgresql installed on my Mac. Not sure why I was getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed "psycopg2" in the python site packages folder to "psycopg2-binary", and this fixed my issue.